# Linq check if all values exists in list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of object named OfferPriorities and OfferPriority has a field TypeId. I want to make sure that all TypeId values are exists in OfferPriorities. Possible TypeId values are 1,2 and 3. I want to check if all of them exist in OfferPriorities. For example below TypeId 3 does not exist in list so i should throw an exception.

---

### Id  |  TypeId

### 5   |  1

### 6   |  2

Comment: `const int MAX_TYPE_ID = 3; bool ok = meList.All(e => e.TypeId <= MAX_TYPE_ID);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Except` + `Any` do what you want:

```
bool allExist = !new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Except(OfferPrioritie.Select(x => x.TypeId)).Any();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Except(OfferPriorities.Select(p => p.TypeId))` ?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility could be to use `All` in to check whether `OfferPriorities` contains all elements:

```
List<OfferPriority> OfferPriorities = new List<OfferPriority>();

OfferPriorities.Add(new OfferPriority() { TypeId = 1 });
OfferPriorities.Add(new OfferPriority() { TypeId = 2 });
//OfferPriorities.Add(new OfferPriority() { TypeId = 3 });

List<int> allowedIDs = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

bool check = allowedIDs.All(x => OfferPriorities.Select(y => y.TypeId).Contains(x));
```

Comment: +1 as this option is more readable. Except+Any feels like its doing the opposite of what we want, and may be confusing to the reader.